# Type.GetMethod() for custom class returns NULL

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm having troubles getting my `MyClass` `== operator`'s method reference when specifying the comparison type while using `Type.GetMethod()`, here is my code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public MyClass(object inVal = null)
    {
        Value = inVal;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(MyClass a, string b)
    {
        // If one is null, but not both, return false.
        if (((object)a == null) || ((object)b == null)) return false;

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return Convert.ToString(a.Value) == b;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MyClass a, string b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(MyClass a, bool b)
    {
        // If one is null, but not both, return false.
        if ((object)a == null) return false;

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return Convert.ToBoolean(a.Value) == b;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(MyClass a, bool b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }
}
```

A call to

```
var methodInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("op_Equality", new Type[]  {  typeof(bool)  } )
```

or

```
var methodInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("op_Equality", new Type[]  {  typeof(string)  } )
```

, returns `NULL`, why is that? I expected a reference to the operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality/inequality operators works on two types,
(in your case the class type and the bool/string type), 
you need to pass also the class type (in the correct order expected)

```
Type t1 = typeof(MyClass);
var methodInfo1 = t1.GetMethod("op_Equality", 
                  new Type[]  { t1, typeof(bool)  } );
var methodInfo2 = t1.GetMethod("op_Equality", 
                  new Type[]  { t1, typeof(string)  } );
```

Answer (score 1):

The normal method expects a public instance method to look for. As yours are static methods, you should use an overload of `GetType` that you can pass a `BindingFlags` parameter of `Static`.

Comment: This is not a problem here. Wrong type is the problem, see the accepted answer.